# Wordpress: compare one date coming as custom field with current date

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know how to compare a date coming as custom field with the current date in a custom loop. I have following script, but it does not work...

```
enter$args = array(
'post_type' => 'books',
 'meta_key'=>'course_date',//the format comes like this Ydm
'meta_value'=> date('d.m.Y'),
 'meta_compare'=> '<'

);
```

My goal is to show all books with when the date is > then the current date. If the current date is > then the related post must be hidden.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Query to get past event list ( 'compare' => '<') and get future events ( 'compare' => '>=')**

```
$event_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'books',
        'meta_query' =>  array(
                array(
                        'key' => 'course_date',
                        'value' => date('Ymd'),
                        'type' => 'DATE',
                        'compare' => '<'
                )
        ),
        'paged'     =>$page,
        'meta_key' => 'course_date',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
);
```